# Android: Is onPause() guaranteed to be called after finish()?

Tags: java, android

Couldn't find a solid answer to this anywhere.  I have a method where finish() is being called, and onPause() is called afterward.

Is onPause() guaranteed to be called after a call to finish() ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Android will generally call `onPause()` if you call `finish()` at some point during your Activity's lifecycle unless you call `finish()` in your `onCreate()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    finish();
  }



  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
  }
}
```

Run, and observe that your log will only contain "onDestroy". Call `finish()` almost anywhere else and you'll see onPause() called.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you even find this? Was there a resource you read at some point, or did you just play around with your code one day? What a corner case.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving your activity (though it does not always mean the activity is being destroyed). This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session (because the user might not come back). so
`onPause()` is guaranteed..The official documentation  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

**EDIT 1**

`onCreate()` is to `onDestroy()` && `onStart()` is to `onStop()` && `onResume()` is to `onPause()` .. `onStart()` is called when `onCreate()` finishes its work. if not its not called.. `onResume()` indicates the ui is about to be shown to the user -(An Activity's content is the screen the user sees).
if you call `finish()` in `onCreate()`, `onPause()` will be skipped because `onResume()` was never called same goes to `onStart()` .. so in some cases you can say its not; but that will be false, because what's an Activity that is not a screen or serve as a container for screens-(Fragment).

and why would you call finish(); directly in your Activity's `onCreate()`? **F**rom how Activities work in general, `onPause()` will always **guarantee** is calling..

Comment: I thought there was a chance that finish() may bypass the onPause() call, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Scratch that, apparently there are scenarios where onPause() is not called.

Comment: scenarios that are not legit to how activities be, that is if you have a legit activity.. check my edit @KacyRaye

Answer (score 3):

Yes, whenever you activity is going to be disappeared, onPause is called.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but may help future visitors.

I faced the problem of `onPause()` not being called when I tried to make an *splash screen* for my app following [**this tutorial**](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/).

After some fiddling around and forcing my mind I figured out why! the `onCreate()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**So before the activity gets a chance to get *started* or *resumed* I was forcing it to be finished and so bypassing the other *state method calls*!**

But as far as I know from the [official `Activity` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in any other situation (at least normal ones!) the `onPause()` method is guaranteed to be called!